# Как разместить два стека в одном массиве?

Tags: java, data-structures

Как разместить два стека в одном массиве?
Реализовал вот так, нужно что бы два стека размещались в одном массиве, как это сделать?

```
public class Stac {
    private int maxSize; //razamer steka
    private long[] stacArray;
    private int top; //top steka

    public  Stac(int s)
    {
        maxSize = s;
        stacArray = new long[maxSize] ;
        top = -1;
    }

    public  void push(long j) //vstavka elementa
    {
        stacArray[++top] = j;
    }

    public long remove() //izvlechenie elementa
    {
        return  stacArray[top--];
    }

    public  long read()  //chtenie elementa
    {
        return stacArray;
    }

    public  boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return  (top == -1);
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (top == maxSize - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, где тут у вас два стека? Во-вторых, метод read() вопреки своему названию и вашему комментарию возвращает не элемент, а размер массива. В третьих, что будет с вашим стеком, когда вы попытаетесь в него добавить `(s + 1)`-ый элемент или извлечь элемент, который не был предварительно добавлен?

Comment: Это класс который описывает стек , мне нужно что бы когда я создал 2 экземпляра этого класса, их элементы записывались в один массив .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автор, почитайте про паттерн проектирования *синглтон*, может Вам нужен именно он? Ибо данная постановка задачи звучит весьма странно (и вообще непонятно, зачем это все нужно).

Но я все же попробую воплотить в реальность задачу автора (*опять же, если я правильно ее понял*) на простом примере.

Класс `Data`:

```
public class Data {

    private static int[] mArray;
    private static int mSize;

    public Data(int capacity) {
        if (mArray == null) {
            mArray = new int[capacity];
            mSize = 0;
        } else {
            // some actions
        }

    }

    public void add(int value) {
        if (mSize < mArray.length) {
            mArray[mSize] = value;
            mSize++;
        } else {
            // some actions
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++) {
            System.out.print(mArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Data dateOne = new Data(7);

dateOne.add(1);
dateOne.add(2);
dateOne.add(3);

Data dateTwo = new Data(15);

dateTwo.add(4);
dateTwo.add(5);
dateTwo.add(10);

System.out.print("dateOne: ");
dateOne.print();

System.out.print("dateTwo: ");
dateTwo.print();
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
dateOne: 1 2 3 4 5 10 
dateTwo: 1 2 3 4 5 10
```

Поля `mArray` и `mSize` объявлены как `static`, этим достигается необходимое:

> мне нужно что бы когда я создал 2 экземпляра этого класса, их элементы записывались в один массив

В данной реализации вместимость массива задается с помощью конструктора при создании первого инстанса (вызовы конструктора при всех последующих созданиях объектов этого класса будут проигнорированы).

**UPD**. По поводу расширения:

```
public Data(int capacity) {
    if (mArray == null) {
        mArray = new int[capacity];
        mSize = 0;
    } else {
        mArray = Arrays.copyOf(mArray, mArray.length + capacity);
    }
}
```

В таком случае при втором и последующих вызовах конструктора емкость массива будет расширяться на `capacity`.

Comment: То есть с помощью модификатора static , массив создается только один раз , а при следующих созданиях экземпляра уже расширяется?                                                                                                   ' Ибо данная постановка задачи звучит весьма странно (и вообще непонятно, зачем это все нужно)'                                (Это задание по Алгоритмам и структурам данных)@post_zeew

Comment: @МаксимШемет, В данном примере массив создается один раз (при создании первого экземпляра данного класса). При последующих созданиях экземпляров данного класса с этим массивов ничего не происходит.

Comment: Если я задал при создании первого экземпляра размер 7 , полностью заполнил его , создал второй экземпляр и добавляю еще один элемент, то он не добавится так как переполнение, да?

Comment: @МаксимШемет, Да.

Comment: @post_zeev, А можно сделать так , что бы при вызове второго экземпляра , массив расширялся ?

Comment: @МаксимШемет, Да, можно. Смотрите **UPD** в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Есть стандартный замечательный класс [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) в котором все уже сделано. Объявляете экземпляр статичным и вперед.

Comment: Это конечно понятно , но задание реализовать два стек самому , на базе одного массива .